# HTML5: Can you render a 20x1 table as a 10x2 table using only CSS?

Tags: css, html

I have an standard HTML table which is 20 rows and 1 column.

The table is a standard 'old-school' HTML table, consisting of standard table tags:

```
<table>
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Row 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 4</td></tr>
    <!-- ... -->
    <tr><td>Row 19</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 20</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

*In this application, it's probably a misuse of the `<table>` tag, and should have been done in a `<dl>`, `<dt>`, `<dd>` format… but that's a discussion for another time.*

I'm wondering if there's a pure CSS method of making a single column table into multiple columns, specifically 10 rows and 2 columns, taking my current table from this format:

```
+-----------+
|     1     |
+-----------+
|     2     |
+-----------+
|     …     |
+-----------+
|     20    |
+-----------+
```

To this format:

```
+-----------+-----------+
|     1     |     2     |
+-----------+-----------+
|     …     |     …     |
+-----------+-----------+
|     19    |     20    |
+-----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely. Of course the best way would be semantic HTML for the content, but I know that can't always be done.

The easiest way way to change the display mode of the table elements. Without knowing the exact layout you have, I've decided to change it to a simple flex box, though you can use any display modes that would suite your needs. `inline-block` with fixed widths, `block` with `float: left`, etc would all work similarly.

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box}table{border:1px solid green}tr{border: 1px solid red}td{border: 1px solid blue}

tbody {
  width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

tr {
  flex: 50%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>6</td></tr>
    <tr><td>7</td></tr>
    <tr><td>8</td></tr>
    <tr><td>9</td></tr>
    <tr><td>10</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```